# Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Recently,I encounter a problem :

```
- (void)popToVC {
    FirstViewController *f1 = [FirstViewController new];
    f1.text = @"1111111";
    SecondViewController *f2 = [SecondViewController new];
    f2.text = @"2222222";
    ThirdViewController *f3 = [ThirdViewController new];
    f3.text = @"3333333";
    FirstViewController *f4 = [FirstViewController new];
    f4.text = @"4444444";
    FirstViewController *f5 = [FirstViewController new];
    f5.text = @"5555555";
    FirstViewController *f6 = [FirstViewController new];
    f6.text = @"6666666";
    [f2 addChildViewController:f3];
    [f2 addChildViewController:f4];
    [f2.view addSubview:f3.view];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:f1 animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:f2 animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:f5 animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:f6 animated:YES];
    // [self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];
    });
}
```

When I execute this code, then get a exception like this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'.

If I uncomment `[self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];`  and delete the next line code `dispatch_after`, then nothing happens.

Why when I write `[self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];` into `dispatch_after`, the code crashes, and it doesn't if I don't use `dispatch_after`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the push and pop sequence are batch operations. As long as the first operation is successful, the rest errors will be passed.

```
// [self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:f1 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:f2 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:f5 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:f6 animated:YES];
```

Now you uncomment the first line, an error will produce. But if the first line is at the end of operations, nothing happened. Similarly,

```
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // [self.navigationController popToViewController:f5  animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];
});
```

Uncomment the first line will not bring about any problems, as long as the first operation has been successfully executed.

An extreme example is like the following which still be fine.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:f1 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:f2 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:f5 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:f6 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:f1  animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:f3 animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:f6 animated:YES];

});
```

Hope this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks! So the `popToViewController:` method only executed separately while can be fine. Once a batch of `push` or `pop` operations are executed, but the first executed `pop` operation is not first, then the whole `popToViewController` is invalid. So everything is seem like fine.